# Can I update existing document without _id?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using elasticSearch version 1.5

I want to updating exist document without _id

_id is auto generated.

how can I without searching update the Document ?

_id has another unique key.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [update by query](https://github.com/yakaz/elasticsearch-action-updatebyquery) plugin you can utilize. This would be your best option. But then if you are trying to update a large amount of documents in a single call , this might not work out.